# IO Exception: Got minus one from a read call

Tags: database, exception, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ioexception

I am getting the below error while trying to connect to oracle database through sql developer.

```
IO Exception: Got minus one from a read call.
Vendor Code 17002
```

The database is up and running. I have checked the sqlnet.ora file, validate node checking is set to "no"

```
tcp.validnode_checking = no
```

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot that shows how you are connecting to the database? Also make sure that the provided port is not blocked.

Comment: The provided port is not blocked. I can provide you the screenshot at night. But it seems like port is open. Because when I restarted the database server, I am able to connect, but after few hours its being giving the error. Also no other application is connected to the database at this moment.